# bind's path to 'named.pid' looks a bit weird after a not-so-smooth package installation

Tags: bind, pidfile, plesk

I had a fresh VPS hosting account running Ubuntu LTS (Lucid Lynx) with Plesk 10.2.0 (and *etckeeper* package)

I used Plesk's web interface to install *Plesk Health Monitor*. It took two attempts because the first time it was aborted half way through.

Unnerved by the fact that the first installation was aborted, I went to *[etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/)* (a tool that puts `/etc/` directory under version control with git) to see what changes had occurred. I noticed a diff in a file called `/etc/init.d/bind9` where a line had changed from:

```
PIDFILE=/var/named/run-root/var/run/named/named.pid
```

to

```
PIDFILE=/var/named/run-root/var/named/run-root/var/run/named/named.pid
```

It might be nothing, but I just thought it was a bit weird to see the path having so many repetitions in it.

So, I'm interested in knowing :

**Should I be concerned about seeing its path change in such a way after a not-so-smooth installation?**

---

Here's some background info if you're interested...

Shortly after my first login to the fresh server, I installed *etckeeper* (with git) to watch changes in my `/etc` directory. *etckeeper* has been both a curse and a blessing. When I first set it up, I made the mistake of uncommenting the `#AVOID_COMMIT_BEFORE_INSTALL=1` line in the `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf`. This change caused a problem when I, then, used Plesk's  *Update or Install Plesk Products Tool* to add a *Plesk Health Monitor*. The installation of that package was aborted with the message:

```
** etckeeper detected uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
** Aborting apt run. Manually commit and restart.
```

I went back into the `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` and commented out the `#AVOID_COMMIT_BEFORE_INSTALL=1` line. I then re-tried using Plesk's  *Update or Install Plesk Products Tool* to add a *Plesk Health Monitor*. This time the installation was successful. It was then that I used `etckeeper` to check the diffs, mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your new version of bind is [chrooted](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_chroot.htm) into a jail under `/var/named/run-root`. This is a method used to add additional security to potentially vulnerable software.

Since my opinions on CMS systems such as Plesk are not printable, I'll decline to comment on that aspect of your question.

Comment: Thanks. So, are you saying that this is quite a normal path and I should not really be worried about it?

Comment: I'm quite explicitly not saying *anything* about how Plesk may or may not decide to manage your filesystem layout for you. I'd recommend going to the Plesk discussion boards to see if this is known behavior.